# How to get a list of element nodes

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, nodes, element

I'm learning HTML and JavaScript currently, and I'm having trouble understanding nodes/elements, and how to log them. I'm taking an online course which corrects my code using a bot.
This is my in HTML file with what is required:

```
<body>
    <section id="players">
      <h1>Players</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>Alice</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Cesar</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I need to create an 'array-like' value which contains three element nodes: One for every 'list item' in the HTML structure above, and I need to save the 'array-like' value in a variable called `items`

This is my JavaScript code so far, but it doesn't work...

```
let items = document.getElementsById('players')
console.log(items[0])
```

The bot output is:

```
index.js
    ✓ exists
    ✓ is valid JavaScript
    1) defines items such that it contains three elements
    2) defines items such that it contains three list item elements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select the list items, so use `querySelectorAll` (or `getElementsByTagName`) to select those `<li>`s:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
console.log(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Players</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Cesar</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

If you need to select only `<li>`s which descend from the `players` element, use the descendant selector (a space) between the `players` selector and the `li`:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
console.log(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Players</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Cesar</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: How should I use JavaScript code to assign an element object that represents the section 'element' to the variable 'section'? (Using the same HTML code)

Comment: `querySelector('section')`?

Comment: ```const items = document.querySelector('section');``` gives me a bot output of:  1) ```defines section of the object type Element = incorrect```
     ``` 2) defines section such that it corresponds to the section element = incorrect```

Comment: Look again - `querySelector`, not `querySelectorAll`, to get a single element

Comment: Sorry, ```querySelector``` was the method I used, I wrote the wrong method. Output is still the same

Comment: Works just fine here, it selects the `<section>` element

Comment: This now worked for me ```const section = document.querySelector('section');
console.log(section[0], section[1], section[2]);```

Comment: That won't work, `querySelector` returns an element, not a collection - those will all log `undefined`